# How to get npm packages with dependency to github projects from Nexus oss proxy

Tags: npm, nexus3

we work in a private network without internet connection. 
recently we decide to setup nexus oss to use npm , maven and other dependency management systems. 
but when we set npm registry url to nexus proxy url , with this command :

```
npm config set registry /*proxy url*/
```

some packages got error while installing , because of its dependencies to github projects .
how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem occurred when you only set npm registry .
you should set proxy to nexus oss url with this command :

```
npm config set proxy /*nexus proxy url*/
```